# How to get current GPS Location at a time?

Tags: android, gps

I have simple flow: when I click the Button I should get current Latitude/Longitude at that time only, 
I am using LocationListner for this but problem is that the method onLocationChange() is calling only when I change the location otherwise gives 0.00/0.00. what shoukd I do please help me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513485/how-do-i-get-the-current-gps-location-programmatically-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant really ask Android to provide you with the current GPS locations right away your best bet would be wait till it gets a location Changed Update or use the Last Known values !

You can use the last known location.

Have a look here:

[What is the simplest and most robust way to get the user's current location on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145089/what-is-the-simplest-and-most-robust-way-to-get-the-users-current-location-in-a/3145655#3145655)

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

```
 LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
 mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
        mlocListener);

 public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
    loc.getLatitude();
    loc.getLongitude();

    Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
            Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        mAddresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                loc.getLongitude(), 1);

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }

    String cityName = (mAddresses != null) ? mAddresses.get(0)
            .getLocality() : TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
    String countryName = (mAddresses != null) ? mAddresses.get(0)
            .getCountryName() : Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry()
            .toString();


    mCurrentSpeed.setText("Longitude"+loc.getLongitude()+" Latitude"+loc.getLatitude());
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your location listener that remembers delivered locations, probably averaging them in some way.